# how to hide the status bar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, customization

Is there a way to hide the quite large status bar cluttering the bottom of the eclipse window ? (where the heap status, line and column count and further non-essential info is shown). 
I am forced to work on a tiny screen here so I already have the [fullscreen plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/fullscreen-mode) installed and hide the regular toolbar per default, but a few more pixels would definitely help ease the pain of a 4:3 19".

Comment: You have your answer here : http://superuser.com/questions/108668/can-i-get-rid-of-the-status-bar-at-the-bottom-of-eclipse

Comment: You call 19" tiny? I used to work on a 12" screen (notebook), and found it manageable (though a bit cramped). But appetite comes with eating, as they say... ;-)

Comment: @sleske Its mainly the resolution - on my notebook (@home) I've got used to 1920x1200 on 15,4". And yes you're right - It is still manageble, I guess I have had too much of [Jeffs bill of programmer rights](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/the-programmers-bill-of-rights.html) :)

Comment: @sleske I doubt you enjoyed Eclipse status bar on that monitor either...

Comment: @h22: No, I don't think I used Eclipse. [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) to the rescue - and in vim the status bar is configurable :-).

Answer (score 12):

I found another solution in my research of using the eclipse dark color theme: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3heiL.png

Solution requires to edit css of eclipse. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17027501/2790481

- If you've installed eclipse-color-theme plugin, you can just copy paste to Eclipse IDE -> Window -> Preferences -> Appearances -> Chrome Theme -> CSS:

  `#org-eclipse-ui-trim-status,
   #org-eclipse-ui-trim-vertical1, 
   #org-eclipse-ui-trim-vertical2 
      {
         visibility: hidden;
      }`
- If you use a custom theme then you'll have to edit that plugin's CSS. E.g. I had to edit this file **eclipse\plugins\com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.moonrise-ui_0.8.6.jar\themes\css\moonrise-ui-standalone.css** and add the above CSS code at the end of moonrise-ui-standalone.css.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by using quick access.
type 'toggle visibility' should find the command that will hide the status bar at the bottom of the window.

Comment: I think this is the best answer (at least for Neon 3) because there's no need to install anything nor mess around with CSS. Windows > Navigation > Quick Access Then search for 'Toggle Visibility' and click it. Done!

Comment: In newer Eclipse versions, Windows > Navigation > Find Actions.

Answer (score 1):

With the coming release of Eclipse, you'll be able to hide the status bar via menu.

see: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501811

Comment: More specifically: Window > Appearance > Hide/Show Status Bar