# Hide status bar or progress bar in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide

How can I hide the status bar in Eclipse? I mean the one at the bottom, where also the "Progress" status is shown. It is very distracting because it is doing something all the time.

I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645495/how-to-hide-the-status-bar-in-eclipse), but the answer given there and on Superuser does not show how to hide it. I also did not find anything in the preferences. I am using Eclipse 3.7.2.

How can I hide the status bar, or at least, get rid of the "Progress" bar at the bottom?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to hide the status bar in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645495/how-to-hide-the-status-bar-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 30):

With CSS in Eclipse Juno there are endless possibilities to style Eclipse the way you like: edit the `eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/css/e4_default_mac.css` (adapt it to your Eclipse version and operating system).

There, add the following lines:

```
#org-eclipse-ui-trim-status,
#org-eclipse-ui-trim-vertical1,
#org-eclipse-ui-trim-vertical2 {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Now, not only the status bar but also the bars on the left and right are hidden. Before doing that, you might open the views you like to have and bring them to your preferred positions and assign a shortcut to them so that they will pop up whenever (and only when) you need them. Of course, you can undo that change any time.

Comment: Is it also possible before Juno? My version is 3.7.2.

Comment: Great!! you are the Awesome Dude.. it works like charm on my MAC Book!! Thank you a lot for sharing this. :)

Comment: +1000, got some screen real estate back from Eclipse. Of course, now the scrollbars stick out like a sore thumb, which is apparently an SWT limitation based on a couple hours of scouring the net for a solution...

Comment: in eclipse luna, its now org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.1.v20140819-1717

Comment: also, how does one go about finding out the element ids for parts of the ui to develop additional css styles?

Comment: @chrismarx now in org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.1.v20141126-1957 as of 4.4.2 M20150204-1700

Comment: In eclipse mars the CSS is in "plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.1.0.v20150511-0913/css"

Answer (score 5):

#### [Eclipse Oxygen (4.7)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/)

**Approach 1**

1. Go to **Quick Access** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>)

   [image: Quick Access]
2. Type "*status bar*"
3. Choose **Toggle Statusbar - Toggle the visibility of the bottom status bar**

**Approach 2**

1. **Window** > **Appearance** > **Hide Status Bar**

   [image: Hide Status Bar]

   This feature is described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/platform.php#hide-show-status-bar).

Answer (score 1):

With the new release of Eclipse, you can use the menu to hide the status bar.

see: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501811