# Where is the CSS file for Eclipse 3.8 located?

Tags: linux, eclipse

I am using Eclipse 3.8 on Linux. I have researched how I can hide the statusbar/progress bar on the Eclipse interface and found the following solution:

[Hide status bar or progress bar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186089/hide-status-bar-or-progress-bar-in-eclipse)

Which suggests an edit to the Eclipse style sheet. They reference the following directory:

```
eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/css/e4_default_mac.css
```

Which I am unable to locate, or anything similar to it. I have searched in the .eclipse subfolder of my user home directory, to no avail.

Where can I find the CSS file for Eclipse 3.8 on Linux? Thank-you.

Comment: This part of the Eclipse install directory

Answer (score 0):

I am using eclipse 4.4 on linux mint mate, it could hide the toolbar via "Window -> hide toolbar", and also 4.4 is improved a lot than previous version, especially on linux.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is not what I want to do. I want to hide the bottom bar which is making the UI look bloated. unfortunately installing 4.4 is not an option since it fails to get past the splash screen.

Comment: @user3803763 Ok, in that case, you can try a plugin named "fullscreen", search in google, download it, unzip, put the jar into eclipse_home/plugins, then restart eclipse, then use ctrl + alt + z to switch between full screen & normal screen.