# Eclipse Luna 4.4 fullscreen

Tags: eclipse, fullscreen

How to switch to fullscreen editor mode in Eclipse Luna 4.4? I know the ^m shortcut for maximizing current editor window, but it's not what F11 fullscreen gives in Chrome or in SublimeText.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Eclipse Neon (4.6)

[image: Window Appearance Toggle Full Screen]

Details in [M7](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M7/):

> The **Full Screen** feature is now also available on Windows and Linux. You can toggle the mode via shortcut (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) or menu (**Window** > **Appearance** > **Toggle Full Screen**).

Comment: This is it! And it takes only 2 years! My life is ok again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The question is about Eclipse Luna. That not works in Luna.

Comment: @Kurapika , strictly speaking, you are right. But the usefulness is more important than stringency. This post should be useful in the future, when many people will be interested in Eclipse, not in a specific version. We already have 2 newer versions (Mars & Neon) and after a while we'll have even more.

Comment: The shortcut doesn't work, even after config the shortcut explicitly, instead `window -> appearance -> toggle full screen` works.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure whether it works on eclipse Luna.[This](http://www.scharf.gr/eclipse/fullscreen/update/) plugin works on eclipse kepler. Blog on this is [here](http://michaelscharf.blogspot.com/2009/06/every-pixel-counts-new-eclipse.html)

Check [how to hide the status bar in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645495/how-to-hide-the-status-bar-in-eclipse) . Hide toolbar from `Window > Hide Toolbar` and check [Hide Eclipse Menu Bar (auto-hide)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380421/hide-eclipse-menu-bar-auto-hide) 
 for hiding menu bar

Comment: thank you! already googled this one. trying to install it but got 'unsigned content warning' so I was looking for something more official (from eclipse or at least from eclipse marketplace).

Comment: The plugin works in Luna, but the menu item does not appear - so it can only be used with the Alt+F11 shortcut.

Answer (score 7):

I just checked on Eclipse 4.4.2 on Windows this plugin
[Eclipse Full Screen Plugin (now 1.0.7) for Eclipse 3.4](https://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fullscreen/) and it works flawlessly :-)

Just unzip the downloaded file and copy the jar file to the plugins directory of your Eclipse. Then restart the Eclipse. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or `Window -> Full screen` options to turn it on.

Comment: That works in Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 running on Ubuntu 16.04 with MATE dektop.

Comment: That's great. Good to know.

Comment: Works on Eclipse Mars

Comment: I'm sorry @EricWang, I don't use Eclipse anymore and I don't know how to updated this answer. Any help would be appreciated in order to update my answer.

Comment: @Pawel The new version of Eclipse has built-in full screen feature, can toggle that via `alt + F11` by default.

Comment: Thanks @EricWant. I haven't used Eclipse for a long time now.

Answer (score 2):

For the full screen part, I would try [Eclipse Full Screen Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fullscreen/).
I'm not aware of an editor mode for eclipse, but you could just hide the toolbar, and maximize the editor window.

Answer (score 0):

I do expect to release my 'CodeFocus' feature to the Eclipse Marketplace once we get Luna out. I showed this off at EclipseCon this year; it's a command that's provides a 'proper' full-screen mode for a given perspective. It hasn't been hacked on enough to be available in Luna directly...

**Update**: The 'CodeFocus' plugin can be found here: https://github.com/fredrikattebrant/CodeFocus

Comment: Hello Eric, the Eclipse Luna is out for a while, could you please tell me if there is the CodeFocus available somewhere on the net? Thank you.

Comment: Very useful, this removes all the clutter (toolbars, sidebars, etc) with Ctrl + '+'. Sadly it does not actually make the window itself fullscreen, and does not work at the same time as the fullscreen mode of [this](http://www.scharf.gr/eclipse/fullscreen/update/) plugin.