# Eclipse: How can I move my footbar?

Tags: eclipse, ide, swt

[image: Move footbar]

How can I move this ugly thing?

Comment: You can drag drop anything with drag handle (4 dots)

Comment: @LifeH2O Yes. [example](https://s22.postimg.org/4vumayr0h/12-04-_2016_08-30-21.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should have a drag handle (the dots) on the bottom left of your screen (minimize & maximize window to make them appear). Maybe this also depends on your OS window system, as Eclipse is based on [SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/).

It is a pity you cannot put this footer bar somewhere else than left or bottom as it is mostly empty ...
I suppose using [Eclipse Fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365921/eclipse-luna-4-4-fullscreen) would remove it.